# How to extract pure unique values (no duplicate values) in R?

Tags: r, duplicates, unique

I'm trying to extract pure unique values in R.

For example:

```
vec <- c("a", "b", "c","c")
```

Using `duplicate()` I get:

```
vec[!duplicated(vec, fromLast=TRUE)]
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

But I want the pure unique values, so only `"a"` and `"b"`.

Using `unique()` I get the same output.

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Try this `vec[!(duplicated(vec)|duplicated(vec, fromLast = TRUE))]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code with `ave` which counts the `length` of unique values and takes only the elements whose length is 1 to skip the duplicates:

```
vec <- c("a", "b", "c","c") 
vec[ave(vec, vec, FUN = length) == 1]
```

Output:

```
[1] "a" "b"
```